# Inserting latin chars in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that contains latin chars like `á`, `é`, `ç` etc. I can insert tuples with those chars using the MySQL admin interface by writing the SQL insert statements there. I can also read and display them without any problem. But I can't insert new data properly using PHP.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "budgets");
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, "bananá");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO items(id_budget, description, unit_price, quantity) VALUES (1, ?, 3, 3);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $data);
$stmt->execute();
```

I have read several threads suggesting to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, and making sure the charsets were configured properly, but nothing worked.

I tried using different charsets in the database but the `á` is always replaced by strange symbols. Currently I'm using `utf8_general_ci` as the charset of the database.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: try using `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`, also check if `mysqli::set_charset` is set to `utf8`

Comment: using mysqli_real_escape_string is unnecessary when using bind_param.

Comment: try to set the character set to utf8 `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")` use [mysqli.set-charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Answer (score 1):

First thing setup your table rows collcation to `utf8_unicode_c`

And add `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` to your connection code

Finaly your code should look like this :

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(HOST_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
if($mysqli === false) {
 die("Something was wrong ! Please try again later."); // Error if connection not ok.
} 
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$data = "bananá";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO items(id_budget, description, unit_price, quantity) VALUES (1, ?, 3, 3);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $data);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```